# How to prevent GWT compile on deploy to app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm trying to debug some server side Java that can't be done on devappserver (involving Blobstore API & GCS, currently not supported on devappserver). I'm using Eclipse. How do I prevent unnecessary time consuming GWT compiles every time I re-deploy after a code change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found so far is to use [appcfg](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp) to deploy after making server-side changes, instead of using Eclipse. An additional benefit is that it deploys faster.

Comment: Thanks that works, but it doesn't accept my password. In the end I had to change the google setting https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps  to make Access for less secure apps enabled. Is this what you do?

Comment: Ok figured out I need to use --oauth2 option